# base class list<type> property to/from derived class list<derivedType> property

Tags: c#, inheritance

Can't quite figure out the dynamics of base/derived `List<type>`.  The main project "Derived" references "Base" project.  Base project works fine and mods need to be kept to a minimum.  Derived project only adds interaction with a service but doesn't modify Base functionality per se.

Base classes:

```
B1
{
  private int _prop;
  int prop
  {
    get{return _prop;}
    set{_prop = value;}
  }
}

B2
{
  private List<B1> _list;
  List<B1> list
  {
    get{return _list;}
    set{_list = value;}
  }
}
```

Derived classes:

```
D1:B1
{
  int prop
  {
    get{return base.prop;}
    set{base.prop = value;}
  }
}

D2:B2
{
  List<D1> list
  {
    get{return base.list;}/Problem area ... each base.B1 needs to be cast to a D1.
    set{base.list = value;}//... each D1 needs to be cast back to a B1
  }
}
```

Each B1 in base.list must be cast to a D1 in order to use the D1 specific methods which in turn interact with the outside service.  Have tried this but am not sure it is a better strategy.  (Overloaded constructors exist to support this.)

```
        get
        {
            List<D1> listD1 = new List<D1>();
            foreach (B1 b in base.list)
            {
                listD1.Add(new D1(B1));
            }
            return _listD1;
        }
        set
        {
            List<B1> listB1 = new List<B1>();
            foreach (D1 d in list)
            {
                listB1.Add(new B1(d.prop));
            }
            base.list = listB1;
        }
```

Is there a more elegant way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't, and this method is potentially dangerous. You may need to re-evaluate what you're trying to do.

`B2.list` is a collection of `B1` objects. Its interface contract states that it contains `B1`'s. In your derived class, `D2.list` is a collection of `D1` objects. Since `D1` is a subclass of `B1`, this is a more stringent requirement. It is entirely possible that the base class's list contains an object that is a `B1` but not a `D1`. In this case your code will fail with an invalid cast exception.

So the language isn't designed to let you do this, because it isn't safe; *you are trying to narrow (rather than extend) the behavior of a base class*. This is often a [code smell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). You will have to do this explicitly, and **only** if you know this is both safe and a good design for your specific problem.

Also, as an observation, note that you are ["hiding" the base class's properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691135%28v=vs.71%29.aspx). The compiler is probably giving you a warning about this. If you want a true override, you need to make the base property `virtual` and use the `override` keyword in the derived class. Or, use the `new` keyword to confirm that hiding is what you want, and eliminate the warning, but make sure you understand what that means (you won't get polymorphic behavior if accessing the property via a reference of the base class type).

Comment: Very helpful ... thank you.  Yes, this is a special case wherein the base properties must be accessible in derived as derived properties due to derived static methods.  Hence, derived properties now have unique names and all is well.  Again, thanks.